# Insert and delete complex structure

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following classes that represent tables:

```
public class PriceDefinition
    {
        public virtual long Id{get;set;}
        public virtual IList<Rule> Rules{get; set;}
        public virtual IList<PriceDefinitionAddition> Additions{get; set;}
        public virtual IList<CustomerPrice> CustomersPrices { get; set; }

        public PriceDefinition() { }
}

public class Rule
{
    public virtual long PriceDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public virtual string FieldName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Values { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }

    public Rule() { }
}

public class CustomerPrice
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual long PriceDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public virtual long TaskPriceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Price TaskPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CustomerAdditionPrice> AdditionsPrices { get; set; }

    public CustomerPrice() { }
}

public class CustomerAdditionPrice
{
    public virtual long CustomerPriceId { get; set; }
    public virtual long AdditionId { get; set; }
    public virtual long PriceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Price Price { get; set; }

    public CustomerAdditionPrice() { }
}

public class Price
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal PriceSum { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal PricePercent { get; set; }
    public virtual long? UnitTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual UnitTypeWrapper UnitTypeWrapper { get; set; }
    public UnitTypeEnum UnitType { get { return UnitTypeWrapper; } }

    public Price() { }
}

public class PriceDefinitionAddition
{
    public virtual long PriceDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public virtual long AdditionId { get; set; }

    public PriceDefinitionAddition() { }
}
```

I have an id of PriceDefinition and I have to delete all the related data. Do I have to iterate over all this complicated structure? How can I use include then load the object in order to load the entire structure? Is there any simple way to delete all this structure?

I have PriceDefinition object and I have to insert in including all its related data. How can I do it in a way that when I call SaveChanges all the id's will get apropriate values? Do I have to iterate all the elements in order to insert all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve deletion - use cascade deletes in both database and Entity designer. If you don't use cascade deletes you must indeed load the whole structure to your application and delete entities one by one.

To solve insertion - prepare your new entity with all new related entities and simply use `AddObject` on the main entity. It will also adds all related entities not tracked by the context. If your Ids are generated by database and correctly set with [StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/the-bug-in-storegeneratedpattern-fixed-in-vs-2010-sp1/) in your entity designer you don't have to do anything more.

Edit:

Another way is simply use stored procedure to delete the structure if it is too complex because loading the structure and deleting entities one by one (= one DB round trip for each delete) can be very slow.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: Ok, so I have to delete entities one by one (some of the entities are soft delete). How can I load the entire structure (there is include for child objects and grandchild objects..) Is there any "LoadAll" or something?

Comment: @Naor: No there is no load all. You must specify includes manually for the whole structure.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: Why do you write "one DB round trip for each delete"? Can't I use SaveChanges at the end of the proccess?

Comment: @Naor: Yes you can, but EF doesn't have command batching so it executes each command as separate round trip to DB - I'm sure it does this for Insert and Upadate but I didn't check it for Delete. I believe it will be the same. `SaveChanges` makes these commands part of single transaction.

Comment: In my case I didn't want to use cascaded deletes because I didn't feel it was safe. (wanted to reduce possibility of human error of a dba deleting a record without realizing it can trigger multiple deletes). On the other hand I didn't want to load the whole thing with EF, so I ended up running delete sql statement against the database with  context.ExecuteStoreCommand

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: I have tasks table and workers table which is complex structure. tasks table has "worker_id" FK. If cascade delete on, worker delete will also delete his tasks so I can't use cascade delete. Doesn't microsoft support this kind of scenario? Does they intend that we delete complex object one by one?